# IFC less object properties in model derivative translation compared to when translated in ACC

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

If I use my own Forge Viewer program which takes an IFC file as input and displays it in Viewer, I get properties like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVYZk.png) for an object.

However, if I instead download the same model to our Autodesk Construction Cloud hub, I get properties like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXDXA.png).

So in other words, by using the viewer in ACC, I get much more properties which is exactly what I want. Would it be possible to get these same properties when using the model derivative API? How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you used the legacy IFC conversion method.

To get the same result as Autodesk Docs(a.k.a. ACC Docs), you must specify the conversion method to either modern or v3.

```bash
curl --location --request POST 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'x-ads-force: true' \
--data-raw '{
    "input": {
        "urn": ""
    },
    "output": {
        "formats": [
            {
                "type": "svf",
                "views": [
                    "3d"
                ],
                "advanced": {
                    "conversionMethod": "v3" // or change it to modern
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}'
```

The main difference between modern and v3, as I know, is that the modern one uses feet as the length unit always. But on the other hand, the v3 method uses IFC file native length unit. So, choosing either of them depends on your use case.

ref: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/#body-structure